# Testing Expected Exceptions with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I want to Unit Test this simple activity (Please focus on the *onClick()* function):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText edtValue1;
    private EditText edtValue2;
    private TextView txtResult;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private Button btnMuliply;

    private ICalculator calculator;

    final String LOG_TAG = "MainScreen";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtValue1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value1);
        edtValue2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value2);
        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addValues);
        btnMuliply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyValues);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMuliply.setOnClickListener(this);

        calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int val1 = 0;
        int val2 = 0;

        try {
            val1 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue1.getText().toString());
            val2 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue2.getText().toString());
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, exc.getMessage(), exc);
            throw exc;
        }

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.addValues:
            txtResult.setText(calculator.addNumbers(val1, val2).toString());
            break;

        case R.id.multiplyValues:
            txtResult.setText(calculator.multiplyNumbers(val1, val2).toString());
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The facade looks like this :

[image: Facade]

Here is the simple JUnit Test Case (Please focus on the *testAddDecimalValues_NumberFormatException()* method):

```
public class MainActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    MainActivity mainActivity;
    private TextView txtResult;


    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mainActivity = getActivity();
        txtResult = (TextView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.result);
    }

    private final static String NUMBER_24 = "2 4 ENTER ";
    private final static String NUMBER_74 = "7 4 ENTER ";
    private final static String ADD_RESULT = "98";


    @After
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddValues() {
        sendKeys(NUMBER_24 + NUMBER_74 + "ENTER");

        // get result
        String mathResult = txtResult.getText().toString();
        assertTrue("Add result should be 98", mathResult.equals(ADD_RESULT));
    }



    private final static String NUMBER_5_DOT_5 = "5 PERIOD 5 ENTER ";

    @Test(expected = NumberFormatException.class)
    public void testAddDecimalValues_NumberFormatException() {
            sendKeys(NUMBER_5_DOT_5 + NUMBER_74 + "ENTER");
    }

}
```

When I launch Unit Test *testAddValues()* works perfectly but *testAddDecimalValues_NumberFormatException()* method doesn't take into account the `expected = IllegalArgumentException.class` and *testAddDecimalValues_NumberFormatException()* test failed...

Here is the Logcat :

```
[2015-05-27 12:52:42 - SimpleCalcTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 0123456789ABCDEF
[2015-05-27 12:52:42 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
[2015-05-27 12:52:42 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run finished
[2015-05-27 12:52:43 - SimpleCalcTest] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2015-05-27 12:52:44 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NumberFormatException'
[2015-05-27 12:52:44 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run finished
```

The question is: **do you know how I could test an expected exception with *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2* functionnalities ?**

Thank you so much.

PS : I tried differents approach from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/testing-expected-exceptions-with-junit-rules.html but I have got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2* can't test an expected exception because *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2* is used to automate a manual testing and, a manual testing mustn't meet an exception...
That's why, in order to test an error case, we would have to make an Unit Test only on business class.

In *MainActivity* class, I have to handle the exception. I can post my code solution if you want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` extends `junit.framework.TestCase`, so you cannot use the annotations or classes in the `org.junit` tree (like `@Test` and `ExpectedException`) with tests that use `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`

Instead, do this:

```
public void testAddDecimalValues_NumberFormatException() {
  try {
    sendKeys(NUMBER_5_DOT_5 + NUMBER_74 + "ENTER");
    fail("NumberFormatException not thrown");
  } catch (NumberFormatException expected) {
  }
}
```

*Edit:* The second problem is with your non-test code. When you catch an exception, you have only three options:

1. Catch the exception, log the exception, and move on without throwing
2. Catch the exception, wrap the exception with another exception, and throw the new exception (without logging).
3. Retry the operation 1-n more times, and if it still fails, do option 1 or 2 (for experts only; this option may make sense for remote calls,, and you need to be aware of the cost of throwing an exception on a loop)

Note with option 2 the exception will either get handled by the calling code or logged by the calling code, so there is no need to log the exception if you plan on throwing it.

So replace this:

```
try {
  val1 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue1.getText().toString());
  val2 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue2.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, exc.getMessage(), exc);
  throw exc;
}
```

With this:

```
val1 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue1.getText().toString());
val2 = Integer.parseInt(edtValue2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I have tried this solution (according to this link [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/testing-expected-exceptions-with-junit-rules.html)  ) . This logcat appears :

[2015-05-27 18:07:33 - SimpleCalcTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 0123456789ABCDEF
[2015-05-27 18:07:34 - SimpleCalcTest] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2015-05-27 18:07:37 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NumberFormatException'
[2015-05-27 18:07:37 - SimpleCalcTest] Test run finished